# Heroku, hhvm, pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, hhvm

HHVM doesn't currently include the postgres extension, but there is one available that we use on a linode server. We would like to migrate everything to Heroku, but we require HHVM to push it (pure PHP is too slow).

So, how/can we do this? I've tried pushing the `pgsql.so` extension up with the code and modifying the `hhvm_app.conf` file we use to load the dynamic extension (as works currently), but it fails without even an error.

Does this require an `heroku-nginx-hhvm-pgsql` buildpack?

Is this even possible currently?

Comment: There's a command that will let you shell to a configured Heroku dyno, changes go away when you disconnect but you can use it to see where things are laid out. I'd try setting the HHVM INI option to where the dynamic extensions are set into your app dir somewhere, and load it that way -- have you tried something like that? Do you know if it's actually loading your configuration file at all?

Comment: Yep, tried that yesterday. Didn't error, but didn't load the extension either.

Comment: We'll bundle the `pgsql` extension for HHVM with the new 3.6.0 release which should be out any day now. Stay tuned :)

Comment: @dzuelke: Where will that be announced? hhvm's github or pocketrent's?

Comment: Neither; by "we" I meant Heroku. HHVM 3.6.0 was tagged six hours ago, so I we'll make it available on Heroku soon, including the `pgsql` extension.

Comment: Oh damn, even better :)

Comment: @dzuelke any updates on this? I currently tried using heroku-nginx-hhvm but got a PDOException with "could not find driver" when trying to run my migrations for pgsql. I also tried using HHVM 3.6, but it's unfortunately not available (yet?).

Comment: @dzuelke I ran across this thread recently and assumed hhvm 3.6 would be out by now but doesn't look like it... only hhvm 3.5.1 which still doesn't support postgres. Any thoughts or predictions?

Comment: We just gave up and switched over to php 7. Performance is great and pgsql works wonderfully.